# How to get SPfile versions?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, version-history, spfile

I'm making a .txt to store each version of a file after I perform a certain action.

The code I'm running is simple:

```
write("version number: 0.1");
write("modified : " + file.Item["Created"].ToString());
write("modified by: " + file.Author.Name);
write("Check in comment : " + file.CheckInComment);

foreach( SPFileVersion version in file.Versions){
  if (version.VersionLabel != "0.1"){
      write("version number: "+ version.VersionLabel);
      write("modified : " + version.Created.ToLocalTime());
      write("modified by: " + version.CreatedBy.Name);
      write("Check in comment : " + version.CheckInComment);
  }
}
```

The code does not go inside the foreach. If the code I wrote is correct, that means my files does not have any versions stored? If so, how do I do this?

I added a new .docx on a library, did check-out and check-in. Edited the file with another user, and then again a check-out and check-in. But I can't seem to get in the foreach.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the code does not go inside the foreach? It might be the if condition is not valid?

Comment: It does not go inside. I put a break point on both, the foreach and the if.

Comment: Are you using CSOM? Is so did you load the file.Versions?

Comment: Is the versioning enabled for the document library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try below code**

```
List LibraryName = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(lib); 
clientContext.Load(LibraryName);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "";

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection collListItem = LibraryName.GetItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.Load(collListItem, items => items.Include(item => item.File.Versions));
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
{
    foreach (FileVersion version in oListItem.File.Versions)
    {
        if ("0.1" != version.VersionLabel)
        {

        }
    }
}
```